# Split pyspark dataframe to chunks and convert to dictionary

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe which looks like the following:

```
+----+--------------------+
|  ID|               Email|
+----+--------------------+
|   1|  sample@example.org|
|   2| sample2@example.org|
|   3|   sampleexample.org|
|   4|   sample@exampleorg|
+----+--------------------+
```

What I need to do is to split it into chunks and then convert those chunks to dictionaries like:

```
chunk1
[{'ID': 1, 'Email': 'sample@example.org'}, {'ID': 2, 'Email': 'sample2@example.org'}]

chunk2
[{'ID': 3, 'Email': 'sampleexample.org'}, {'ID': 4, 'Email': 'sample@exampleorg'}]
```

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012312/spark-possible-to-split-dataframe-into-parts-for-topandas) on SO but I figured it would not make any sense to first convert the chunks to pandas dataframe and from there to dictionary while I might be able to do it directly. Using the idea in that post, I've got the following code but not sure if this is the best way of doing it:

```
columns = spark_df.schema.fieldNames()
chunks = spark_df.repartition(num_chunks).rdd.mapPartitions(lambda iterator: [iterator.to_dict('records')]).toLocalIterator()
for list_of_dicts in chunks:
    # do work locally on list_of_dicts
```

Comment: Why do you want to create chunks before converting it to dictionary? What is the criteria for the chunks (equal amount of entries)?

Comment: @cronoik data is large and I don't have enough memory for all of it. chunk sizes could data size / 10k or something like that. So basically 10k rows per chunk

Comment: are you looking for a new solution or fixing your existing solution?

Comment: @jxc either or. I am basically trying to avoid using pandas if possible. I am wondering if I could convert to dictionary directly, instead of converting my partitions to pandas first and then to dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can return `[[x.asDict() for x in iterator]]` in the mapPartitions function (no need Pandas). `[x.asDict() for x in iterator]` creates a list of dicts including all rows in the same partition. we then enclose it using another list so that it was treated as a single item with `toLocalIterator()`:

```
from json import dumps    

num_chunks = 2
chunks = spark_df.repartition(num_chunks).rdd.mapPartitions(lambda iterator: [[x.asDict() for x in iterator]]).toLocalIterator()
for list_of_dicts in chunks:
  print(dumps(list_of_dicts))
#[{"ID": "2", "Email": "sample2@example.org"}, {"ID": "1", "Email": "sample@example.org"}]
#[{"ID": "4", "Email": "sample@exampleorg"}, {"ID": "3", "Email": "sampleexample.org"}]
```